# How to set up complex condition composite foreign key in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, declarative

Here's my ORM entity class. The primary key is composite cause 'id_string' may be the same for different users (identified by uid). One thing I understood from Postgres SQL error when creating a table based on this class (

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "sync_entities"
```

) is that I need to add something to parent_id_string's ForeignKey() argument. And that something is, I think, the current record's uid.

Do you suggest to try using different primary key (autoincrementing integer) or there is some other way?

```
class SyncEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sync_entities'
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(['uid'], ['users.uid'], ondelete='CASCADE'), {})

    uid = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)

    id_string = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    parent_id_string = Column(String, ForeignKey('sync_entities.id_string'))
    children = relation('SyncEntity',
                        primaryjoin=('sync_entities.c.id_string==sync_entities.c.parent_id_string'),
                        backref=backref('parent', \
                                        remote_side=[id_string]))

    # old_parent_id = ...
    version = Column(BigInteger)
    mtime = Column(BigInteger)
    ctime = Column(BigInteger)
    name = Column(String)
    non_unique_name = Column(String)
    sync_timestamp = Column(BigInteger)
    server_defined_unique_tag = Column(String)
    position_in_parent = Column(BigInteger)

    insert_after_item_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('sync_entities.id_string'))
    insert_after = relation('SyncEntity',
                            primaryjoin=('sync_entities.c.id_string==sync_entities.c.insert_after_item_id'),
                            remote_side=[id_string])

    deleted = Column(Boolean)
    originator_cache_guid = Column(String)
    originator_client_item_id = Column(String)
    specifics = Column(LargeBinary)
    folder = Column(Boolean)
    client_defined_unique_tag = Column(String)
    ordinal_in_parent = Column(LargeBinary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, primary key being an auto-incremented integer is usually the best approach. Any values that seem to be unique in system, may turn out to be duplicated in future. If you relied on their uniqueness you're in deep trouble.

However, if there is a reason to require certain pair (or triple) of values in each row to be unique, just add constraint to your table, but use auto-increment integer as primary key. Then if requirements change, you can alter/remove/relax your unique constraint without making changes elsewhere.

Also - if you're using simple integer keys, your joins are simpler and can be performed faster by DBMS.

Comment: Note: this is very pragmatic advice, but also shortcircuits the relational model where the idea is that you think deeply about what makes up the 'identity' of a relational row.  Having a 'real' composite primary key will mean that you can look at the key as it appears as a foreign key in another table, and actually see what is going on without having to chase up what the key '430021' refers to in the main table.
Also, if requirements change, you can always add an autoincrementing column and transfer primary key status to it.

Comment: Once I believed in the relational model, 3NF and modelling actual entities by table rows. But then I started working and found out that entities are identified by 3-5 columns, which are big integers or varchars and using them as foreign keys requires on update cascade triggers and makes whole system slower. Actually, even when you trace object relationships through your db, it's easier to find it in main table and note down one key, instead of check value of 5 columns in several tables which have 30-60 columns each. But suit your needs - as always :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a good idea. Just need to create complex foreign key constructs in the **__*tableargs*__** member like (parent_id_string, uid) and (insert_after_item_id, uid), modifying the primaryjoin statements accordingly.